# JDK 8: ConcurrentHashMap.compute seems occasionally to be allowing multiple calls to remapping function

Tags: java-8, concurrenthashmap, atomic

I'm working on a highly concurrent application that uses an object cache based on a `ConcurrentHashMap`. My understanding of `ConcurrentHashMap` is that calls to the "compute" family of methods guarantee atomicity with respect to the remapping function. However, I've found what appears to be anomalous behavior: occasionally, the remapping function is called more than once.

The following snippet in my code shows how this can happen and what I have to do to work around it:

```
private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Object> cachedObjects 
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(100000);

private ReadWriteLock externalLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private Lock visibilityLock = externalLock.readLock();

...

public void update(...) {
    ...
    Reference<Integer> lockCount = new Reference<>(0);
    try {
        newStats = cachedObjects.compute(objectId, (key, currentStats) -> {

            ...

            visibilityLock.lock();
            lockCount.set(lockCount.get() + 1);
            return updateFunction.apply(objectId, currentStats);
        });
    } finally {
        int count = lockCount.get();
        if (count > 1) {
            logger.debug("NOTE! visibilityLock acquired {} times!", count);
        }
        while (count-- > 0) {
            // if locked, then unlock. The unlock is outside the compute to
            // ensure the lock is released only after the modification is
            // visible to an iterator created from the active objects hashmap.
            visibilityLock.unlock();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Once in a great while, `visibilityLock.lock()` will be called more than once within the `try` block. The code in the `finally` block logs this and I do see the log message when this happens. My remapping function is mostly idempotent so, with the exception `visibilityLock.lock()`, it's harmless to have it called more than once. When it is, the `finally` block handles it by unlocking multiple times as needed.

`visibilityLock` is a read lock obtained from a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. The point of this other lock is to ensure that another data structure outside this one cannot see the changes being made by the `updateFunction` until after `compute` returns.

Before we get side-tracked on non-issues, I'm already aware that the default implementation of `ConcurrentMap.compute` indicates that the remapping function can be called multiple times. However, the override (and corresponding documentation) in `ConcurrentHashMap` provides a guarantee of atomicity and the implementation shows this to be true (afaict).

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is it a JDK bug, or am I just doing something wrong?

I'm using:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `visibilityLock` that isn't already done by concurrentmap?

Comment: In fact, what is the type of `visibilityLock`?

Comment: Thanks @Ben - I forgot to mention the type of `visibilityLock` - I've updated the text accordingly - along with info on why we feel we need it. The reasons for needing it are not obvious from the snippet - suffice it to say that we do.

Comment: I see. My first suggestion is to validate your belief that you have a ConcurrentHashMap by putting in a runtime type check for the concrete type, and check your JDK version and documentation has the same guarantee of atomicity.

Comment: @SeanBright - note that `lockCount` is a local variable. Therefore, there is no contention via multiple threads. If `lockCount` is greater than one when we hit the `finally` block, it can only be because the single call to `compute` called the remapping function (lambda) more than once. Note also that the lock is the reader lock in a reader/writer lock. Therefore multiple threads can lock this lock. The only concern with `lockCount` is how many times this happened in this single call to `compute` (so I don't leave an outstanding reader lock in effect).

Comment: You said before that it was a re-entrant mutex, now you say it is the reader lock of a reader/writer lock. Firstly, These are not consistent statements. Secondly: If you are writing to the data structure take the writer lock, not the reader lock.

Comment: @Ben - I don't see anywhere on this page where I indicate it's a reentrant mutex. It's always been the reader lock of a reentrant read/write lock. I believe I did say in my first edit adding lock info that it was a reentrant mutex, but then changed it so that it reads as it does now a couple of minutes later. Sorry if that confused you. The way we use the reader/writer lock is not consequential to the issue at hand. We do use it the way we need to in the rest of our code. This portion is the only place we use the reader lock.

Comment: @SeanBright - I guess the point of this SO article was to find out if anyone else has experienced this issue. We know the issue exists, and we know how to work around it, but we don't know why it's happening. Was just hoping for a little extra insight if anyone else has run into it and discovered anything about it.

Comment: @seanbright Maybe John is a fire-and-forget questioner, and once he has his solution doesn't care if others benefit.

Comment: @seanbright If you're waiting for me to provide a green check for the one "answer" provided (so far), you'll be waiting a while. I'm not going to mark an answer as the "accepted" answer unless it actually solves the problem. The only value in Ben's answer is a set of good debugging techniques - which was not the answer to any question I asked.

Comment: Still working on it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Eyeballing the JDK code:

- https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java

It's apparrent that compute will not call the `remappingFunction` twice. That leaves three possibilities:

- You don't have a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but something else. Check the concrete type at runtime and dump it to the log file.
- You are calling `compute` twice. Is there any flow control in the function which may not be doing what you expect? You've removed most of the  function so it's impossible for me to say.
- You are calling `compute` once, but your `remappingFunction` is locking twice. Is there any flow control in the lambda which might not be doing what you think? Again, you have removed most of the function so there is nothing I can do to help.

To debug, check the lock count, at the point of locking, and if it is nonzero, dump the stack to the logfile.